# Crash in UIKit UINavigationItem

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a problem with my iPhone app, I have a crash log from a tester that i ran through symbolicatecrash but I'm still not sure what could be causing it. The crash only happens on one tester's device and I am unable to reproduce it on my device.

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone2,1

OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.0.1 (8A306)


Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x534f5031
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000286c objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                          0x000765c6 -[UINavigationItem _updateViewsForBarSizeChangeIfNecessary] + 30
2   UIKit                          0x000a26c8 -[UINavigationBar _popNavigationItemWithTransition:] + 212
3   UIKit                          0x000a25d0 -[UINavigationBar popNavigationItemAnimated:] + 76
4   UIKit                          0x000a2492 -[UINavigationBar _handleMouseUpAtPoint:] + 390
5   UIKit                          0x000a22f2 -[UINavigationBar touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 54
6   UIKit                          0x000614e6 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 362
7   UIKit                          0x00060e60 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 256
8   UIKit                          0x0005cb54 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 292
9   UIKit                          0x0005c500 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5016
10  GraphicsServices               0x00004140 PurpleEventCallback + 660
11  CoreFoundation                 0x00071aa4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
12  CoreFoundation                 0x00073848 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
13  CoreFoundation                 0x00074626 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
14  CoreFoundation                 0x0001d8e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
15  CoreFoundation                 0x0001d7ec CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
16  GraphicsServices               0x000036e8 GSEventRunModal + 108
17  GraphicsServices               0x00003794 GSEventRun + 56
18  UIKit                          0x000062a0 -[UIApplication _run] + 396
19  UIKit                          0x00004e10 UIApplicationMain + 664
20  app                            0x0000240c main (main.m:14)
21  app                            0x000023a8 start + 44
```

The crash happens from taking a photo, going to new view, manipulating photo, saving it, sending it, returning to the previous view and then trying to go back to the view before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're properly retaining and releasing your nib objects as outlined [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmNibObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004998-SW2).